# How to access request type in RAML file (using webapi-parser)

Tags: java, webapi, raml, raml-java-parser

**Library used**
[webapi-parser 0.5.0](https://github.com/raml-org/webapi-parser)

**Language library used with**
Java

**Describe the issue**
I am unable to find a method to access the type of request defined in the raml file

**Input you have issues with**
Below is the relavent section of RAML file

```
/testEndpoint:
      type: rt.Item
      post:
        is: [t.ReturnsItemCreated, t.ExpectsContext, t.ReturnsNotFound, t.ReturnsBadGateway, t.ReturnsCommonErrors, t.NotCacheable]
        body:
          application/json:
            type: bu.BlockCodeUpdatesRequestType
            examples:
              de-cards-bc: !include examples/example1.json
        responses:
          201:
            body:
              application/json:
                type: bu.DeviceManagementResponseType
                example: !include examples/ex2.json
```

**Code you have issues with**
After going through the documentation, I tried using `operation.request().payloads().get(0).mediaType().value()` but that returns `application/json` which isn't what I want, I want the type inside the `application/json` i.e. `bu.BlockCodeUpdatesRequestType`. Same is the case with the examples, I am unable to read those, the `payloads().get(0).examples()` comes up as empty for some reason and I don't know to access these. Getting just the path in the examples is enough.

**Additional context**
The variables like `rt` `bu` are RAML library files defined under `uses:`

I asked the same thing on [Github here](https://github.com/raml-org/webapi-parser/issues/93).